# Replace specific match in .NET RegEx Matches collection

Tags: c#, regex

I am using C# to replace date values within a text file. I am parsing the file line by line and trying to replace the dates individually because I need to take part of the date (the year) and increment it by one. The problem I am having is on the replacement part. If there are duplicate `matches` in the same line (two dates that are the same) then the `Replace` matches both of them and replaces both. Then on the next iteration through the Matches collection fails because the second instance of the match is no longer valid since it has already been replaced. Is there a way to only replace the `match` I am iterating on?

Here is my Regular Expression:
`(\|((\d{2})(.)(\w{2,4})(.)(\d{2}))`

Here is some sample text:

```
111111|atorvastatin 10 mg tablet|13-AUG-14||13-AUG-14|Sent
222222|atorvastatin 20 mg tablet|30-JAN-13|05-FEB-14|30-JAN-13|Sent
333333|simvastatin 10 mg tablet|30-AUG-13|05-FEB-14|30-AUG-13|Sent
444444|lovastatin 20 mg tablet|21-JUN-13|21-JUN-13|Sent
```

Here is my code:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(line, regexPattern);
foreach(Match match in Matches)
{
  int originalDateYear;
  int newDateYear;
  string replacementValue;

  originalDateYear = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[2].Value); //This is the YYYY of the date
  newDateYear = originalDateYear + 1; // Add 1 to the date
  replacementValue = newDateYear.ToString() + match.Groups[3].Value + match.Groups[4].Value + match.Groups[5].Value + match.Groups[6].Value; // Build the new date
  line = line.Replace(match.Groups[1].Value, replacementValue); // Replace the old date with the new date
}
```

Comment: Replace can take a callback function so you can do whatever with the matches. Also you can use the Index and Length properties of the Match object which tell you where in the string to replace, so that you know the exact occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Regex.Replace` overload which takes a callback:

Let's simplify the pattern somewhat:

```
var regexPattern = new Regex(@"(?<date>\|\d{2}.\w{2,4}.)(?<year>\d{2})");
```

Then use it for each line:

```
line = regexPattern.Replace(line,
    match => string.Format("{0}{1:00}", match.Groups["date"].Value, int.Parse(match.Groups["year"].Value) + 1);
```

Oh, and beware of the Y2K bug here :-)

Comment: thanks for the example! Can you expound on the Y2K issue? When I have dates that are `1999` adding one should give me `2000` shouldn't it? Keeping in mind I am not adding to the date. Just the `year` portion of it.

Comment: Well... your example and pattern shows you're using dates with 2 digits for the year... And `99 + 1 = 100`, not `00`. I've also changed the answer to ensure there are always at least 2 digits in the result string.